# Spring-boot async controller via CompletableFuture works synchronicity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I created 2 spring-boot services: **slow-service** and **gateway**
**slow-service** is service which reverses string but do it very slowly.

```
@Service
public class SlowReverseService implements ReverseService {
    @Override
    public String reverse(String message) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(message);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

And Controller:

```
@RestController
public class SlowController {

    private final ReverseService reverseService;

    public SlowController(ReverseService reverseService) {
        this.reverseService = reverseService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/reverse/{message}")
    public String reverseMessage(@PathVariable("message") String message){
        return reverseService.reverse(message);
    }
}
```

**gateway** uses **slow-service** and returns an async result.

```
@Service
public class AsyncReverseService implements ReverseService {

    @Async
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<String> reverse(String message) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
                restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/reverse/" + message, String.class));
    }
}
```

And Controller:

```
@RestController
public class GatewayController {

    private final ReverseService reverseService;

    public GatewayController(ReverseService reverseService) {
        this.reverseService = reverseService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/reverse/{message}")
    public CompletableFuture<String> reverseMessage(@PathVariable("message") String message) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(new Date() + ":" + name);
        return reverseService.reverse(message);
    }
}
```

I set this param in the properties of gateway: `server.tomcat.threads.max=2`
I try to send 6 requests to the gateway and see this log:

```
Thu Aug 13 10:59:28 MSK 2020:http-nio-8080-exec-1
Thu Aug 13 10:59:29 MSK 2020:http-nio-8080-exec-2
Thu Aug 13 10:59:58 MSK 2020:http-nio-8080-exec-1
Thu Aug 13 10:59:59 MSK 2020:http-nio-8080-exec-2
Thu Aug 13 11:00:28 MSK 2020:http-nio-8080-exec-1
Thu Aug 13 11:00:29 MSK 2020:http-nio-8080-exec-2
```

My gateway controller receives 2 requests and sends it to slow-service. Slow-service works 30 sec and returns the result to the gateway. The gateway can process the next 2 requests. The Gateway can process 2 requests each 30 sec.

I Expected another behavior: Gateway receives 2 requests and delegates it to CompletableFuture. And frees threads. And Can receive the next 2 requests. Connections increases but my 2 threads are always available.

Comment: I guess you enabled async `@EnableAsync`. By the way, why your tomcat has only 2 threads `server.tomcat.threads.max=2`? Also did you defined a `TaskExecutor` (even if it's optional)?

Comment: A suggestion: `@Async` shouldn't be used the way you're using. What is more apt for you here is `Spring WebFlux's Mono<Response>`.